# To find the element in DOM without using document.getElementById() generated using *ngFor in angular 2+

Tags: angular

app.component.html:

```
<div *ngFor = "let ivalue of arraytoDispaly;let i = index;">
      <input type="text" id={{i}} [value]="ivalue.inputValue" />
</div>
<button (click)='GetElementValue()'>GetElementValue</button>
```

app.component.ts:

```
arraytoDispaly = [{'inputValue':'abc'},
                  {'inputValue':'def'},
                  {'inputValue':'ghi'}];
GetElementValue(){
 var t = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('1')).value;
 console.log(t);
}
```

Whenever I am clicking on 'GetElementValue' button, I am getting the value of input field with id of '1' as 'def'. Need to know is there any other way to access element generated by *ngFor in angular. Thanks

Comment: how do you know which value to get from 3 of them?

Comment: @mobasiriqbal create a component replace with input pass data you want to show. after that  you will create ` @viewChild` for `ElementRef`.

Comment: lets suppose I want the second input value, which I am getting, but is there any other way to get that value from the input field in angular

Comment: you can dynamically set local variable on template within *ngFor and get the value using `viewChildern`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tag your inputs with a template variable:

```
<div *ngFor = "let ivalue of arraytoDispaly;let i = index;">
      <input #inputs type="text" id={{i}} [value]="ivalue.inputValue" />
</div>
<button (click)='GetElementValue()'>GetElementValue</button>
```

Then you can use `@ViewChildren` and query for the ElementRef using the `QueryList` API:

```
@ViewChildren('inputs', 
    { read: ElementRef }) inputs: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

The possible values for `read` are: 
`ElementRef`, `ViewContainerRef` or name of the Component/Directive itself (useful if you have more than one directive on an element).

Initialize the elements if you need to by implementing `AfterViewInit`:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   // so something with inputs
}
```

You also have access to `inputs` via a click handler:

```
GetElementValue(){
   var t = (<HTMLInputElement> this.inputs.toArray()[1].nativeElement).value;
   console.log(t);
}
```

Or more succinctly using `map`:

```
 GetElementValue(){
    var t = (<HTMLInputElement> this.inputs.map(t=>t.nativeElement)[1]).value;
    console.log(t);
 }
```

For more information, here is everything you need to know about how to use @ViewChildren:

https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-viewchild/